# How can I find a teacher who is a stream entrant?

Tags: teachers, meditation-teachers

How can I find a teacher who is a stream entrant?

Any suggestions? Recommendations?

Comment: It's good, in my view, to keep the perspective of looking for *someone*, a teacher ***by personal contact***. I've recently come to the -a bit sarcastic, of course- reasoning that there might a tendency begin to occur to settle with _video-stream-entering_ instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Into the Stream -- A Study Guide on the First Stage of Awakening](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html)
and [The Power of Judgment](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/headandhearttogether/Section0006_en.html) might help.

It's all a matter of having done what leads to [blessings](https://youtu.be/ijshNb7Mt0M) -- and "dwelling" in [borderlands](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8884.msg16105.html#msg16105):

> A monastery, traditional Wat (pi: vatta) is an outwardly borderland ...
>
> A "borderland" is a "state" between home and homelessness, outer lands and noble domain ...

*[DD, post not given for trade or any wordily exchange]*

Comment: This @Medhiṇī seams to be... it's by an element that beings gather together, again and again... give a fool knowledge: all he would be able is to destroy his last little goodness....

Comment: @Medhiṇī I reversed this edit (see also [Is the disclaimer necessary?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2186/254)).

Answer (score 2):

Mirror of Dhamma:

> Stream-entry is often called the arising of the Dhamma eye. What stream-enterers see with this Dhamma eye is always expressed in the same terms: "Whatever is subject to origination is all subject to cessation.

[‘When you know for yourselves...’ --
The Authenticity of the Pali Suttas](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/authenticity.html)

Answer (score 0):

A stream enterer understands that everything happens perfectly automatically according to conditions, and identity is only due to the illusion of unified experience.